# glsl wrong light direction

Tags: shaders, glsl

I'm practicing the Phong lighting model with glsl, and here's my shaders:
vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 aNormal;

out vec2 TexCoord;
out vec3 LightColor;
uniform mat4 model;
layout (std140) uniform coord_mats {
    mat4 view;
    mat4 projection;
    vec3 lightPos;
    vec3 lightColor;
};

void main()
{
    vec3 vertex_position = vec3(model * vec4(aPos, 1.0));
//    vec3 vertex_position = vec3(view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0));
    vec3 vertex_normal = normalize(vec3(model * vec4 (aNormal, 1.0)));
//    vec3 vertex_normal = normalize(vec3(view * model * vec4 (aNormal, 1.0)));
    vec3 light_position = vec3(vec4(lightPos, 1.0));
//    vec3 light_position = vec3(view * vec4(lightPos, 1.0));
    vec3 light_dir = normalize(light_position - vertex_position);
    float diff = max(dot( light_dir,vertex_normal), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColor;
    vec3 ambient = 0.1 * lightColor;
    LightColor = diffuse + ambient;

    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoord;
in vec3 LightColor;
// texture sampler
uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(LightColor,1.0) * texture(texture1, TexCoord);
}
```

The diffuse light works right, that is, faces which are facing to the light source, are bright, when backing the light source, they are dark(basically ambient color).

Now I want to calculate the specular light, in order to get the camera position for free, I changes the coordinate to camera view coordinate(using the commented code, just multiply the view matrix to the vertex position, normal and light position), but weird things happened: all faces which are facing the light is dark, all faces which are backing to the light is bright.

How could this happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I cannot put a comment yet, however, I noticed that you have 'w' set to 1 in your normal i.e. it would be translated as well. It might have caused this issue.

Comment: Hi, I think you find the root case, but I'm confused, since when translating vertices, we add w to 1.0, but when translating normals, we set w to 0, why?

Comment: It is because normals are directions and not positions.  It makes sense to translate your player's position. For example, lets say your player's position is {0,0,0}. Now move the player 5 units in x positive direction. Now your player's position is {5,0,0}, however, lets say your player's up vector is {0,1,0}, it does not make sense to move the player's up vector by 5 units to the right. If you do that your normal would become {5,1,0} which is wrong. In nutshell, it does not make any sense to translate a direction.

Comment: You can also watch [3D fundamentals videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqCJpWy5Fohe8ucwhksiv9hTF5sfid8lA) on Youtube. This tutorial explains all the 3d fundamentals in really depth.

Comment: thanks so much, I will investigate'